# DateTimeFormatter - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many pattern letters: a

Tags: java, date-format, java-time, zoneddatetime, datetimeformatter

I have the following line in my `java` code where I am trying to format a date string

```
 ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime= ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, tz);
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm aa");

 return zonedDateTime.format(formatter);
```

At line 2 , I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many pattern letters: a
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.parseField(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:1774)
```

How can I create a format string for `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` that will give e.g:

```
2023-04-21 7.00pm
```

Comment: use one `a` only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Use one `a`

As the error describes, you have used too many `a` character codes.

Change `aa` to `a`.

### Localization

You may have been thinking of two letters for AM and PM. But actually, other text might appear instead.

The text generated by `a` depends on the human language and cultural norms used during localization. You specify the language and norms by way of a `Locale`. If omitted, your JVM’s current default locale is implicitly applied.

#### Example code

For fun, let’s try looking at all possible outputs across all locales.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "h:mm a" ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 19 , 0 ) ;
for( Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales() ) 
{
    String s = lt.format( f.withLocale( locale ) ) ;
    System.out.println( locale + " : " + s ) ;
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/yIUMKr).

You can see that many different pieces of text are possible, many are more than two characters. Even those using `PM` or `pm` may have more than two characters when including FULL STOP character: `p.m.`.

```
nn : 7:00 ettermiddag
ar_JO : 7:00 م
bg : 7:00 сл.об.
kea : 7:00 pm
nds : 7:00 PM
zu : 7:00 PM
am_ET : 7:00 ከሰዓት
fr_DZ : 7:00 PM
ti_ET : 7:00 ድሕር ሰዓት
bo_CN : 7:00 ཕྱི་དྲོ་
hsb : 7:00 popołdnju
qu_EC : 7:00 p.m.
ta_SG : 7:00 பிற்பகல்
lv : 7:00 pēcpusdienā
en_NU : 7:00 PM
…
```